# Interaction of a magnetized plasma beam with a dielectric surface

Tags: electromagnetism, astrophysics, plasma-physics, solar-wind

The topic is *inspired* by the interaction of solar wind plasma with bodies without an atmosphere and magnetosphere (the Moon, asteroids etc.), though overall the question is more general. So let's assume we have a beam of magnetized plasma which encounters a flat dielectric surface perpendicular to it.

What would happen to a plasma? In Alfven's book (Cosmic plasma, 1981) the answer is given for the case of a conducting surface: the beam would be diverted (parallel to the surface), and the conductor would experience the corresponding induced currents:

[image: Picture from Alfven's book]

1. What would happen in case of a dielectric surface? How would the picture of fields/currents look? Do I understand it correctly that the picture may be completely analogous, the only difference being that the "surface" part of the circuit would be provided by the displacement current in the dielectric?
2. In this case how "long-lasting" would such a configuration be? Or, reformulating: how would the stationary state look (i.e. if the plasma beam is infinite)? I mean, displacement current can't exist for long due to its nature - ?
3. How would it look in a situation of a plasma with much higher (orders of magnitude) density/velocity/magnetic field strength? E.g. are there any specific nonlinear effects that can manifest here? What if the induced fields would be strong enough to cause the breakdown of the dielectric material, for example?

I'd be grateful for any considerations/links.

Comment: Have you looked at https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005GeoRL..32.9102H/abstract or https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011P&SS...59.1681H/abstract by any chance?  Jasper has done a lot on solar wind-lunar surface interactions.

Comment: Thanks! I've seen some papers on the Moon and Phobos, but not these.
While I'm more interested in a more fundamental electrodynamics of the process, this helps as well.